Unicode Brexit-ascii
I've installed the unicode package using apt install unicode on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS:
unicode/noble,noble,now 3.1-1 all [installed]
  display unicode character properties

The help text shows a peculiar option "--brexit-ascii":
  --ascii               Display ASCII table
  --brexit-ascii, --brexit
                        Display ASCII table (EU-UK Trade and Cooperation
                        Agreement version)

What exactly is this "ASCII table (EU-UK Trade and Cooperation Agreement version)"? I couldn't find any technical information about it. Is there actually such a thing or is it some sort of political protest from the developer?

It's a joke. The EU-UK agreement mentioned here included a copy of ASCII in the appendices (see this post on Politics.SE), but they badly mangled the formatting. From the screenshot provided there:

You can see how that last row is messed up. This option shows that exact table, with the messed up formatting.

Thanks for the link, this is quite amusing! I see that the unicode utility actually gets this wrong. Characters 34 and 39 are not the apostrophe ' but right and left single quotation marks ’ and ‘.

Worth filing a bug report, I'd guess - might as well get the joke just right
